# Using OrchardCore, how do I setup a default index view for the index page?

Tags: asp.net-core, orchardcms, orchardcore

For example, assume I have two projects within a solution

**OrchardCore.WebUI** ( an asp.net core MVC host, which references OrchardCore.Module1)

**OrchardCore.Module1** ( an orchard core module)

I would like a request to https://localhost:44346/ to serve the view from OrchardCore.Module1 > Home > Index

Here is my startup within the **OrchardCore.WebUI** project

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOrchardCore().AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseOrchardCore();
    }
}
}
```

I dont need the CMS or anything at this point, just looking to serve some default view. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The **OrchardCore.WebUI** project has package reference

```
  <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="OrchardCore.Application.Mvc.Targets" Version="1.0.0-rc1-10004" />
```

The **OrchardCore.Module1** project has package reference

```
  <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="OrchardCore.Module.Targets" Version="1.0.0-rc1-10004" />
```

Am I misunderstanding how the index view is setup?
***Fundamentally, I am trying to have the index page be based on the tenant. Also, I need each tenant to be based on the RequestUrlHost, rather than RequestUrlPrefix***

Here
https://orchardcore.readthedocs.io/en/dev/docs/guides/create-modular-application-mvc/
it says

> In the Startup.cs file of MyModule, add this code in the Configure() method.

```
routes.MapAreaRoute(
    name: "Home",
    areaName: "MyModule",
    template: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

That seems to suggest that what I am trying to accomplish is right. However, I cant get this to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In OrchardCore.Module1.csproj is the first line --

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
```

and in the Property Group with the target framework add -

```
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
```

This should resolve the problem